# How can I use the unittest module to assert if a value is in a list?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm currently writing out test cases for a small project using [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), and I'd like to assert that a value is in an iterable. For example:

```
x in [x, y]
```

Is there a `unittest` function that can accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn

Comment: But, use [pytest](https://pytest.org/en/latest/)...

Comment: Thanks, Steven! I may change over to pytest later on, but for now, my project already has a lot with unittest.

Comment: Pytest will run your unittests just fine...

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks for the help, I might try that out!

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found the answer thanks to a comment on this question. (Thanks, Steven!)

The module has an `assertIn` function that I didn’t catch before.